# Why Flutter does not immediately update variable inside setState?

Tags: flutter, setstate, synchronous

So I have code that basically like this:

```
int data;

void function() {
  print("First: $data");
  if (data == null) { 
    this.setState(() => data = 1); 
  }
  print("Second: $data");
}
```

The log will be:

```
First: null
Second: null
```

But if I do it like this:

```
int data;

void function() {
  print("First: $data");
  if (data == null) { 
    data = 1;
    this.setState(() => data = 1); 
  }
  print("Second: $data");
}
```

The result will be:

```
First: null
Second: 1
```

Why it's like this? I thought for a long time the calling of callback inside setState is synchronous? If it isn't then is it better if I do this instead:

```
int data;

void function() {
  print("First: $data");
  if (data == null) { 
    data = 1;
    this.setState(() {}); // nothing in the callback, set state is just marking UI needs to be updated
  }
  print("Second: $data");
}
```

Comment: This link is helpful to understand what is happening: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/setState.html

Comment: the callback is called synchronously, if i call `print('first $foo');
setState(() => foo = 1);
print('second $foo');` i get: `first null<CRLF>second 1.0`

Comment: I think ```setState``` has nothing to do with the value of the variable ```data```. The value should change without calling ```setState```

Comment: @pskink that's what I thought too. But in my recent bug investigation, the result showed me that it is not the case, where I made a simple testing roughly like above. there were also similar case where, for a peculiar need, I call a function from build stage, within the function I had a gatekeeper check `if (isActive == true) return; setState(() => isActive = true);` to make sure the function is not ran concurrently. from the subsequent log after that check, I concluded that the function *is* ran concurrently, which means the `isActive` is not updated immediately and the check is bypassed.

Comment: @EhsanAskari I do thinking of doing things like that from now on, rather than be misled by the synchronization feeling of `setState` and confused later because of bugs that look like not making any sense.

Comment: @DeePanShu I have read that before, and it clearly states it's synchronized. which is why I'm confused because from my log it looks like it isn't.

Comment: @ChenLiYong Can you post a minimal complete code that reproduces the behaviour you observed? I think there must have been something else that gave you those kinds of results, because the code you have posted seems to work fine.

Comment: @Magnus unfortunately as this has already been so long, I forgot which part of my code behaves like that. My workaround if I find this issue is to just immediately follow with a direct assignment. e.g. `this.setState(() => a = 10); a = 10;` with this, nothing goes wrong anymore.

Answer (score 0):

check the implementation of setstate(), https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/setState.html,
this does nothing with the data, it only validates that you have not returned a future.

The only important thing is that at the end it marks the widget to rebuild when the framework can do it with `_element!.markNeedsBuild();`